# If ajax request contains extension file at the end, nginx refuses to process it, instead it calls it statically

Tags: nginx

Trying to install phpmyadmin with project. And I want phpmyadmin to be accessible through http://ip/phpmyadmin

Hovewer I cant figure out why it does not work.

Below is the config

```
        server {
                listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server;                    
                server_name <IP>;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                set $current_doc_root "/var/www/html/project/";

                location /.htaccess {
                        return 403;
                }

                location /site.ini {
                        return 403;
                }

                location / {
                        root $current_doc_root;
                        try_files $uri @proxy;
                }

                location /phpmyadmin/ {
                        root /var/www/html;
                        index index.php index.html index.htm;

                        location /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php\.+ {
                                return 404;
index $uri;
                                try_files $uri =404;
                                root /var/www/html;
                                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                                fastcgi_index $uri;
                                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        }

                        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php) {
                                index index.php;
                                try_files $uri =404;
                                root /var/www/html;
                                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                                fastcgi_index $uri;
                                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        }
                        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                                return 404;
                                root /usr/share/;
                        }
                }

                location /phpMyAdmin {return 404;
                       rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
                }

                location ~ \.php$ {return 404;
                #        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                #        fastcgi_index  index.php;
                #        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $current_doc_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
                #        include        fastcgi_params;
                #        return 404;
                }

                location @proxy {
                        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                        fastcgi_index  index.php;

                        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
                        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
                        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
                        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

                        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $current_doc_root/index.php;
                        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
                        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
                        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
                        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
                        fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

                        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
                        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

                        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
                        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
                        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
                        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
                        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
                        # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-re
                        fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
                }
        }
```

It opens phpmyadmin page, but when page request

```
/phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php?scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js&scripts%5B%5D=sprintf.js&scripts%5B%5D=ajax.js&scripts%5B%5D=keyhandler.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.cookie.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.mousewheel.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js&scripts%5B%5D=jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange-1.3.js
```

via ajax, nginx not passes this to php-fpm, instead it retuns bare file, with php code inside it.

Rule with regex provided above (location /phpmyadmin/js/get_scripts.js.php.+) is not working, nginx just ignores it if it see file extension at the end.

I'm stub for two days.

Comment: Looking at the configuration you provided, it should return 404. This block will handle the request: `location ~ \.php$ { return 404; }`

Comment: .php is not at the end of the url, so this rule is not applied, and yes, I dont see 404 status code

Comment: Nginx uses a [normalized URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) when evaluating `location` and `rewrite` statements, so the URI in your question is normalised to one that ends with `.php`. However, I cannot explain why you are not seeing a 404 response.

Comment: thank you for reply, useful answer. One thing I noticed is that this query is not parsed by any location rule, nginx thinks of it as static, like css, js... I also could not find any global config applying this rule